# React custom hook spit Error " Error: Should have a queue. This is likely a bug in React. Please file an issue"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I have react component which needs to consume a customized react hook from within the component.

However, this hook should only be called when a feature toggle is enabled. I understand this is sort of anti-pattern as it is against the rule of hooks here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

So my component file is roughly in this structure:

```
    const someFeatureToggle = useSomeFeatureToggleHook(React);
    const callBackMethod = ()=>{
        // doing the logic
     }
    const someRef1 = React.useRef();
    const someOtherRef = React.useRef();
    ...
    There are lots of useState( ) here

    return (
        JSX
      )
```

For the customized hook:

```
export default function myCustomizedHook(topics, messagesReceivedFn, subscriptionOptions = {}) {
  if (!isValidTopics(topics)) {
    throw new Error(`Topics arg is invalid - Arg ${JSON.stringify(topics)}`);
  }
  const [someSubTopics] = useState([topics].flat());

  const context = useContext(SomeEventContext);
  if (isUndefined(context)) {
    throw new Error(`${customizedHook.name} must be used within SomeProvider`);
  }
  const { connectionStatus, connector } = context;
  const isConnectorConnected = connector?.connected ?? false;
  const isConnectorReconnecting = connector?.reconnecting ?? false;

  const messageReceivedHandler = useCallback(
    (receivedTopic, message) => {
      if (subscribedTopics.some((topic) => matches(topic, receivedTopic))) {
        messagesReceivedFn?.(receivedTopic, message);
      }
    },
    [messagesReceivedFn, subscribedTopics]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    isConnectorConnected && connector?.on(CLIENT_EVENTS.MESSAGE, messageReceivedHandler);

    return () => {
      connector?.off(CLIENT_EVENTS.MESSAGE, messageReceivedHandler);
    };
  }, [messageReceivedHandler, connector, isConnectorConnected]);

  useDeepCompareEffect(() => {
    isConnectorConnected && connector.subscribe(subscribedTopics, subscriptionOptions);

    return () => {
      subscribedTopics && connector?.unsubscribe(subscribedTopics);
    };
  }, [connector, isConnectorConnected, subscribedTopics, subscriptionOptions]);

  return { isConnected: isConnectorConnected, isReconnecting: isConnectorReconnecting, connectionStatus, subscribedTopics };
```

Now the error trace is like this:

```
Uncaught Error: Should have a queue. This is likely a bug in React. Please file an issue.
    at updateReducer (react-dom.development.js:15255:15)
    at updateState (react-dom.development.js:15671:12)
    at Object.useState (react-dom.development.js:16472:18)
    at useState (react.development.js:1533:23)
    at customizedHook (customizedHook.js:28:38)
    at componentThatConsumeHook (componentThatConsumeHook.js:67:99)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:15015:20)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:17386:22)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19093:18)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3942:16)
```

and there is this warning from dev console in the browser:

```
Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by myComponent. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks: https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks

   Previous render            Next render
   ------------------------------------------------------
1. useRef                     useRef
2. useState                   useState
3. useEffect                  useEffect
4. useRef                     useState
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

line 28 of customizedHook is point to this line below:

```
const [someSubTopics] = useState([topics].flat());
```

This is how I consume the hook in the component:

```
const result = (!!featureToggles.Flag) && customHook(arg1, callbackMethod);
```

I am scratching my head here as I have no clue why this is happening, any thought or advice would be greatly appreciated !!!!

Comment: Conditionally calling hooks is not “sort of an anti-pattern” as you describe it. It results (as you’ve discovered) in plain brokenness. Hooks 100% rely on the fact that they are never called conditionally. Mess around and find out, to paraphrase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you're calling hook inside a condition.

```
const result = (!!featureToggles.Flag) && customHook(arg1, callbackMethod);
```

is basically the same as

```
let result = false
if (!!featureToggles.Flag){
  result = customHook(arg1, callbackMethod);
}
```

From React document:

> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.

What you could do is to pass `featureToggles` into your custom hook and do the check inside that instead.

Make sure your condition check is at the bottom of your hook, below every hook call.

```
// pass featureToggles here
export default function myCustomizedHook(featureToggles, topics, messagesReceivedFn, subscriptionOptions = {}) {
  // your code here

  useDeepCompareEffect(() => {
    isConnectorConnected && connector.subscribe(subscribedTopics, subscriptionOptions);

    return () => {
      subscribedTopics && connector?.unsubscribe(subscribedTopics);
    };
  }, [connector, isConnectorConnected, subscribedTopics, subscriptionOptions]);

  // make sure to do the check at the bottom, below every hook call
  if (!!featureToggles.Flag) {
    // handle this feature toggle
    return null
  }

  return { isConnected: isConnectorConnected, isReconnecting: isConnectorReconnecting, connectionStatus, subscribedTopics };
```